# Removing a CSS Border from Bootstrap Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel that I am using in BS 2.3.

When a panel contains content, I want to show the normal panel with its border etc. However, when there is no content in the body, I want to apply a class to it that removes the border around the panel body so that you are just left with the gray bar in the header.

Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/xwh0ca7c/

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="panel-title"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Training Projects</span></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
      I do not want this border around the "Body" of this panel, just the heading. Really, when I remove the body div, I dont understand why the border is still there to begin with. I need a custom class that will allow me to not show the border / around the panel body
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: -15px -15px 15px;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  font-weight: 500;      
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px -15px -15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
} 

.panel-primary {
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.panel-primary .panel-heading {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
/* This kinda of works but I only want to apply it to specific panels, not all
.panel, .panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{
    border: none;
}
*/
```

Here is a screenshot of how I want the final result on panels I choose; not all of them: 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the border (and box-shadow) of `.panel` and change the border-bottom of `.panel-heading` to border

http://jsfiddle.net/xwh0ca7c/1/

---

2nd solution: now add `noborder` to `panel`

```
.panel.noborder {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.panel.noborder > .panel-heading {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xwh0ca7c/2/

Comment: That's exactly what I need, however just to be certain this will mean I need two sets of this css to accomplish this? My goal is to be able to apply the style to specific panels of my choosing vs all of them.

Answer (score 1):

panel

```
<!-- Test Panel -->
<div class="panel panel-empty">
      <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="panel-title"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Training Projects</span></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.panel-empty{
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    border:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 ;
     box-shadow: 0 ;
}

.panel-empty .panel-heading{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

default class in bootstrap goes:

```
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

just remove the default panel class in your div.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the bootstrap styles and put the border on the body. This will get rid of the body border when there isn't a border and keep it when there is a body. The provided answer so far always removes the border. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr3Lvonn/)

```
.panel{
  border:none;
  padding:0;
}
.panel-heading{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
}
.panel-body{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  border-top:0;
}
```